# How to Create dashboard for structured log files in disk in any tool like Kibana, Grafana

Tags: kibana, grafana, serilog

I have a .net web api application where I have used Serilog and was able to generate both structured logs with custom fields. All log files are stored in a folder in the server. Can I install Kibana/Grafana in the same server to create dashboards using info in the structured log files. Their(Kibana/Grafana) website refer to data sources like Elastisearch or some other but not directly structured logs.

Comment: how would have grafana have access to those files...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I am installing/hosting Grafana in the same server.

Comment: maybe interested in https://community.grafana.com/t/can-grafana-read-values-from-a-application-log-file/5786

Comment: Both Kibana and Grafana require some kind of database to connect to. If you don't want to provision and manage a database, you could just write something to read the files directly and render charts.

Comment: @tomr after some study understood that there is no direct json log feeding possible in either Grafana/Kiban. pls post your comment as answer, ill mark them as answer.  If know about any other analytics platform like(Grafana/Kibana) to process Json properties,  and without the need for another storage feed ie, that accepts directly json logs - please add that point to your answer aswell. Thanks.

Comment: Done, cheers. I added a note about Apache Superset... I know it has an 'upload CSV' button somewhere, but that may be about importing into a running database... you'd need to do some research. Hth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Kibana and Grafana require some kind of database to connect to. AFAIK, so does Apache Superset.

If you don't want to provision and manage a database, you could just write something to read the files directly and render charts.